# AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support array<struct<

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am at work and I need immediate help please
I have a parquet file and I  need to convert it to csv. could u please help me?

error:

```
AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support array<struct<company:string,dateRange:string,description:string,location:string,title:string>> data type.
```

I have never worked with this format so I can't even print schema. sorry

printshema:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Locale: string (nullable = true)
 |-- workExperience: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dateRange: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: It looks like the parquet file has a column that contains an array of struct objects. As csv is a simple text format, it does not support these complex types. You should provide the schema and some sample data of the parquet file (`spark.read().parquet(...).printSchema()`) and the expected output as csv.

Comment: @werner I printed schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parquet schema can be flattened using [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html):

```python
df=spark.read.parquet(...)
flattened_df = df.withColumn("tmp", F.explode("workExperience")) \
    .selectExpr("_id", "Locale", "tmp.*")
flattened_df.write.csv(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't save a dataframe which contains column with array/struct type to CSV. You need to cast the column to string before writing.

```
df.withColumn('workExperience', col('workExperience').cast('string')).write.csv('path')
```

Comment: how can we read back this data and add struct type to column?